# The method sendKeys(String, String) is undefined for the type Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, junit

im working with Selenum, after exporting the test to Junit 4 RC, Im facing compilation error.
the selenium.sendKeys is undefined
(The method sendKeys(String, String) is undefined for the type Selenium)

My environment is Eclipse and the Selenium jars are updated from vertion 3.3 to 3.5

attached code:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class loginGustCOP_NET {
    private Selenium selenium;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://shaula01:7001/");
        selenium.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        selenium.sendKeys("id=categoryId", "0000");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

What can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean version 2.35. You need to use [type(String locator, String text)](http://release.openqa.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#type%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method in order to write text to some input. `sendText` method is only available in Selenium WebDriver.